# Set up pathuto to work for me

Tags: path-aliases

I want to set up pathuto to act like this

http://nevia.server2.tabvn.com/blog/mauris-aliquet-ultricies-ante

How do I accomplish this?
What I want is to have my site behave like this when an article is clicked:
www.domain.com/categorytile/articletitle.

How do I set pathauto to use categorytitle and articletitle like this?

Here is an expanded edition of what I wrote above:

Supposing I have the following 3 categories created on my site:

- healthcare
- technology
- education

Then I post articles in the 3 different categories. 
When a user clicks on an article posted into category "education", the url will look like this: www.domain.com/education/articletitle

My problem is to make pathauto to automatically insert the category name "education" into the urls of all the articles posted into that category.

I want the same with the articles posted into the other two categories. For example, if a user clicks on an article posted into category "technology", then the url will look like this: www.domain/technology/articletitle

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello. Asking to recreate functionality of a linked page is generally unwelcome. If there is something you want to achieve, describe it with your own words please, tell what have you tried and why it's not working for you. It'll be easier that way. If linked site will die tomorrow, your question as it is now will became useless, with all it's answers.

Comment: Tink this is just a request for help with the pathauto settings, ie figuring out the right otokens to use, and not a request to duplicate the actual link.

Comment: It looks like you accidentally created two accounts. Use the CONTACT US link in the footer if you would like the accounts merged.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean content type as category title.

On the Pathauto configuration page `admin/config/search/path/patterns`

Set default pattern as:

```
[node:content-type]/[node:title]
```

Comment: I think his categories are taxonomy, not content types.

Comment: You are right. As I wrote my answer, the question was not clear enough..

Answer (score 0):

If your articles are in only one category, then you can use the replacement token for your category field on the Article. Suppose your Article content type has a field Category (which is a taxonomy term), then your Pathauto pattern would be `[node:field_category]/[node:title]`.